# Run Windows commands without localization

Tags: windows, command-line

Usually, my OS is in German. But some commands have a bad translation, or I want to write a batch script and be sure that localization is not oging to get in my way.

So what is a good way to turn off localization, so that commands like `systeminfo` run with their pure, english output, instead of the localized one?

Comment: can't you install the english package and chage your OS to it?

Answer (score 1):

The majority of Windows binaries is localized so you have no way of making them output English instead of German. The only chance you have is to install a language pack. However, they don't support all versions of Windows.